# In R how can I make a contingency table with five binary factors with gtsummary (or any other r package)

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to replicate a table:

[image] which shows counts of people who are grouped on five binary variables.  I can load the data and get the counts to display with lousy labels like this:

```
Drugs2 <- read.table("http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/cat/data/Substance2.dat",
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

`Table 7.5` <-  bind_cols(`Alcohol Use` = c("Yes", "", "No", ""),
  `Cigarette Use` = rep(c("Yes", "No"),2),
  matrix(Drugs2$count, ncol = 8,byrow = T,
         dimnames = list(NULL,
         c("Y_F_W", "N_F_W", "Y_M_W", "N_M_W", "Y_F_O", "N_F_O", "Y_M_O", "N_M_O")))) 

knitr::kable(`Table 7.5`)
```

I see that the `gtsummary` package can add one level of column labels with the `modify_spanning_header()` function but I don't see how to nest spanning headers.  Does anybody know how I can add nested headers with `gtsummary`?

Can anybody suggest how to produce a publication quality version of this table using `gtsummary` or some other package?

Comment: [`kableExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/) might fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that gtsummary cannot add multiple spanning headers (it's written that way to ensure we support output to multiple formats).

I would try flextable to print this table.  They have functions for adding multiple headers row, and the ability to merge cells (both vertically and horizontally).
https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly for the quick response.  I will play with flextable.